# NSCoding and ostream

Tags: objective-c, iostream, nscoding

Is there a better way to serialize an ObjC object than using /NSKeyedArchive?

I need to distribute the object through a C++ std:ostream-like object to put on another computer.

The object has over 122 members of various types... for which  wants me to

```
[coder encodeObject: (id) forKey: @"blah"];
```

for all of them...

Does anyone have a nice Perl Script that will at least write it out?  I don't even know if the objects it contains implement  which means this could turn into a huge ugly mess since I can't change the source of the object - I'll have to inherit & add the `@interface` to it...

Or am I being dumb?  [Apple's guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Tasks/decoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000950-BAJBIGJC) doesn't help me since archiving to XML won't pass nicely though the ostream.

Is there a better way to do this?

-S!

---

[Edit 1]
So I've looked at NSCoding, and my classes contain generic `NSManagedObjects`... which don't conform to `<NSCoding>`.  I've tried using the Aspect Oriented Programing found [here][2] - but this leads to an infinite recursion at runtime. (at least that's what I assume a call stack of 104795 calls to `[id encodeWithCoder:]` are.

Plus, I can't just add `<NSCoding>` to the class as I'm loading as its members are objects of an imported framework.  I can't just add the protocol to it, which is why I thought the Aspect-Oriented stuff would work.

The last (and terrible) Idea that I have is to subclass every class I need, and implement the protocols there.  A huge roadblock I can forsee is if the classes include NSArrays of Classes not exposed in the framework.  Then I'm sunk.

Is there a better way to do this?  I feel like  is a design-time decision, and it's too late now to be adding this capability.

help...

PS

this whole anti-spam thing with limiting links suck.  How am I supposed to ask intelligent questions!?

[2]:
http:/ /davedelong.com/blog/2009/04/13/aspect-oriented-programming-objective-c#comment-803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `NSCoding` is definitely the right way to go. If you don't want to type all the `NSCoding`-related boilerplate (and I agree, it's a pain), take a look at [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html) which can write it for you.

Comment: I found [this](http://davedelong.com/blog/2009/04/13/aspect-oriented-programming-objective-c#comment-803 "Aspect Oriented Programming ObjC") Which does exactly what I want.  Since I can't actually edit the class (it's in a framework), I didn't want to create a massively disgusting inheritance tree with only adding <NSCoding>.  But... I will use Accessorizer.  That looks heavenly.